# How to Type cast in spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, prepared-statement, uuid, jdbctemplate

I have table is postgres  which stores user information. And I'm executing query as shown below

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "select * from userschema.userlist where id= ?",
                new Object[]{userid},
                (rs, rowNum) -> 
                    new HistorianServer(
                        rs.getString("id"),
                        rs.getString("firstname"),
                        rs.getString("lastname"),
                        rs.getString("address"),
                        rs.getString("userid")
                        )
        );
```

Datatype for id column is uuid and for all other text and I'm getting below error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[@austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14443519/austin) , you need to read id column using `rs.getByte(id)` & then convert the byte[] to UUID yourself.